# Java self-checking program (self-checksuming)

Tags: java, checksum, self

I have to do a little java self-checking programm (self-checksum). 
here my code sample

```
public class tamper {
      public static int checksum_self () throws Exception {
          File file = new File ("tamper.class");
          FileInputStream fr = new FileInputStream (file);
          int result;                   // Compute the checksum
          return result;
      }
      public static boolean check1_for_tampering () throws Exception {
            return checksum_self () != 0; // TO BE UPDATED!
      }
      public static int check2_for_tampering () throws Exception {
            return checksum_self ();
      }
      public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception {
          if (check1_for_tampering ()) {
            System.exit (-1);
          }
          float celsius = Integer.parseInt (args[0]);
          float fahrenheit = 9 * celsius / 5 + 32;
          System.out.println (celsius + "C = " + fahrenheit + "F");
      }
}
```

I have tried to do something like that

```
DigestInputStream sha = new DigestInputStream(fr, MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA"));
byte[] digest = sha.getMessageDigest();

for(..)
{
result = result + digest[i]
}
```

But then i don't really know how to check that ??

EDIT:

Thanks for your answers

@ Adam Paynter and SpoonBenders

Naturally this is not for my personal use. And I wont use that to protect any software.....

It's an "exercice" i have to do for my java course...

Comment: please give attention java method name standards. it is not C or php

Comment: Is this for personal interest? I wouldn't rely on this technique to protect code from modification.

Comment: if your code is running purely on the client-side, it's very hard to protect.  On the other hand, some software only makes sense when there's an Internet connection available.  Such software are trivial to protect **very** effectively: just make part of the computation happen on the server side (server side that you fully control).  Think of this: **nobody** is playing on the real *World of Warcraft* economy/Blizzard servers without having a valid licence.  Nobody.  Not a single pirate group managed to work around that.  *That* is how powerful client/server protections can be.

Comment: @SpoonBender: Completely agreed, in fact I would go so far as to say that if the entire application is on the client it is impossible to protect. You can of course make it very difficult, but witch access to all components any mechanism can be circumvented or disabled eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should take a look at [signed jar files](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signindex.html).

Answer (score 0):

To check you first need to create a checksum. Possibly straight after compilation, you need to run you program in checksum creation mode that will create and store the check sum in a file or elsewhere where you can access at runtime.

Then at run time, you will need to load that checksum, which will be your expected result. Then perform checksumming on "tamper.class" as you have done in your code and check that it matches the expected result.

Is this what you are trying to do?